# Query for Event Log Information of Microsoft-Windows-UniversalTelemetryClient/Operational

Tags: c++, windows, event-log

I read [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/querying-for-event-source-messages) but I want to query for `Microsoft-Windows-UniversalTelemetryClient/Operational` not for `MyEventProvider` in that example. I want use this event log for check internet connection.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I could use [`EvtSubscribe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtsubscribe). The following code is the answer I was looking for:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winevt.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wevtapi.lib")

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

DWORD EnumerateResults(EVT_HANDLE hResults);
DWORD PrintEvent(EVT_HANDLE hEvent);
BOOL IsKeyEvent(HANDLE hStdIn);

#define QUERY_INTERNET2 L"<QueryList>"\
            L"  <Query Id=\"0\" Path=\"System\">"\
            L"    <Select Path=\"Microsoft-Windows-UniversalTelemetryClient/Operational\">"\
            L" *[System[(EventID=55)]] and *[EventData[Data[@Name='State'] and (Data='true')]]"\
            L"</Select>"\
            L"  </Query>"\
            L"</QueryList>"

void __cdecl wmain()
{
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    EVT_HANDLE hSubscription = NULL;
    HANDLE aWaitHandles[2];
    DWORD dwWait = 0;

    // Get a handle for console input, so you can break out of the loop.
    aWaitHandles[0] = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == aWaitHandles[0])
    {
        wprintf(L"GetStdHandle failed with %lu.\n", GetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Get a handle to a manual reset event object that the subscription will signal
    // when events become available that match your query criteria.
    aWaitHandles[1] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);
    if (NULL == aWaitHandles[1])
    {
        wprintf(L"CreateEvent failed with %lu.\n", GetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Subscribe to events.
    hSubscription = EvtSubscribe(NULL, aWaitHandles[1], NULL, QUERY_INTERNET2, NULL, NULL, NULL, EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord);
    if (NULL == hSubscription)
    {
        status = GetLastError();

        if (ERROR_EVT_CHANNEL_NOT_FOUND == status)
            wprintf(L"Channel was not found.\n");
        else if (ERROR_EVT_INVALID_QUERY == status)
            wprintf(L"The query was not found.\n");
        else
            wprintf(L"EvtSubscribe failed with %lu.\n", status);

        goto cleanup;
    }

    wprintf(L"Press any key to quit.\n");

    // Loop until the user presses a key or there is an error.
    while (1)
    {
        dwWait = WaitForMultipleObjects(sizeof(aWaitHandles) / sizeof(HANDLE), aWaitHandles, FALSE, INFINITE);

        if (0 == dwWait - WAIT_OBJECT_0)  // Console input
        {
            if (IsKeyEvent(aWaitHandles[0]))
                break;
        }
        else if (1 == dwWait - WAIT_OBJECT_0) // Query results
        {
            if (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != (status = EnumerateResults(hSubscription)))
            {
                break;
            }

            ResetEvent(aWaitHandles[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (WAIT_FAILED == dwWait)
            {
                wprintf(L"WaitForSingleObject failed with %lu\n", GetLastError());
            }
            break;
        }
    }

cleanup:

    if (hSubscription)
        EvtClose(hSubscription);

    if (aWaitHandles[0])
        CloseHandle(aWaitHandles[0]);

    if (aWaitHandles[1])
        CloseHandle(aWaitHandles[1]);
}

// Enumerate the events in the result set.
DWORD EnumerateResults(EVT_HANDLE hResults)
{
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    EVT_HANDLE hEvents[ARRAY_SIZE];
    DWORD dwReturned = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        // Get a block of events from the result set.
        if (!EvtNext(hResults, ARRAY_SIZE, hEvents, INFINITE, 0, &dwReturned))
        {
            if (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != (status = GetLastError()))
            {
                wprintf(L"EvtNext failed with %lu\n", status);
            }

            goto cleanup;
        }

        // For each event, call the PrintEvent function which renders the
        // event for display.
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwReturned; i++)
        {
            if (ERROR_SUCCESS == (status = PrintEvent(hEvents[i])))
            {
                EvtClose(hEvents[i]);
                hEvents[i] = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                goto cleanup;
            }
        }
    }

cleanup:

    // Closes any events in case an error occurred above.
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwReturned; i++)
    {
        if (NULL != hEvents[i])
            EvtClose(hEvents[i]);
    }

    return status;
}

// Render the event as an XML string and print it.
DWORD PrintEvent(EVT_HANDLE hEvent)
{
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;
    DWORD dwBufferUsed = 0;
    DWORD dwPropertyCount = 0;
    LPWSTR pRenderedContent = NULL;

    // The EvtRenderEventXml flag tells EvtRender to render the event as an XML string.
    if (!EvtRender(NULL, hEvent, EvtRenderEventXml, dwBufferSize, pRenderedContent, &dwBufferUsed, &dwPropertyCount))
    {
        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == (status = GetLastError()))
        {
            dwBufferSize = dwBufferUsed;
            pRenderedContent = (LPWSTR)malloc(dwBufferSize);
            if (pRenderedContent)
            {
                EvtRender(NULL, hEvent, EvtRenderEventXml, dwBufferSize, pRenderedContent, &dwBufferUsed, &dwPropertyCount);
            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"malloc failed\n");
                status = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
                goto cleanup;
            }
        }

        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != (status = GetLastError()))
        {
            wprintf(L"EvtRender failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
            goto cleanup;
        }
    }

    wprintf(L"\n\n%s", pRenderedContent);

cleanup:

    if (pRenderedContent)
        free(pRenderedContent);

    return status;
}

// Determines whether the console input was a key event.
BOOL IsKeyEvent(HANDLE hStdIn)
{
    INPUT_RECORD Record[128];
    DWORD dwRecordsRead = 0;
    BOOL fKeyPress = FALSE;

    if (ReadConsoleInput(hStdIn, Record, 128, &dwRecordsRead))
    {
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwRecordsRead; i++)
        {
            if (KEY_EVENT == Record[i].EventType)
            {
                fKeyPress = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return fKeyPress;
}
```